# Redirect wordpress URL with query string

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to redirect this URL

```
https://example.com/courses/course-name/?purchase-course=5428
```

to this

```
https://example.com/courses/course-name/
```

Where `5428` is the course id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set permalinks for you WordPress see the guide here

1. open your admin.
2. hover on setting into the left side.
3. click permalink.
4. from permalinks click radio button with "post name"
5. hit save button and see it will work as you want

more information here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set permalinks from admin, choose "post name" and save permalinks,

[image]

Comment: Actually, When i add a new course into cart, this URL  
https://example.com/courses/course-name/
is redirected to this 
[https://example.com/courses/course-name/?purchase-course=5428

Comment: So when you adding course into cart, you need to course id to track transaction details right?